# Sniffing Xfinity Voice Remote Connection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, bluetooth-gatt

I am making a universal remote for my home theatre setup using an ESP32-C6 and the first step is controlling all the relevant connections.

I am attempting to sniff the connection between the Xfinity Voice Remote and the Xfinity 4k Cable Box using an nrf52840 dongle. However, I am having no luck. I am only seeing a billion advertising packets with a bunch of different devices, and it is only advertisement packets even when I select an individual device to sniff in Wireshark. Furthermore, I can't even pinpoint which device the remote is because it is not labeled with any good information.

Any tips?

I have tried using the nRF sniffer, but this doesn't help me pinpoint which device is which. I know this is possible because my Samsung smart TV has a built in integration to be able to pair to the cable box, but I can't find the documentation to copy what Samsung did.

Comment: Are you sure the remote works using BLE?